# how to override magento customer module JS files in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, onepage-checkout

I need to override the following file

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/model/customer-addresses.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    './customer/address'
], function ($, ko, Address) {
    'use strict';
var isLoggedIn = ko.observable(window.isCustomerLoggedIn);

return {
    /**
     * @return {Array}
     */
    getAddressItems: function () {
        var items = [],
            customerData = window.customerData;

        if (isLoggedIn()) {
            if (Object.keys(customerData).length) {
                $.each(customerData.addresses, function (key, item) {
                     items.push(new Address(item));
                });
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
};
});
```

> I need to replace `items.push(new Address(item));` with

```
if (item.region.region_code.toLowerCase() === window.getStoreName.toLowerCase()){
 items.push(new Address(item));
}
```

> That's to fetch customer addresses based on current store in checkout page.

Comment: I update the answer with complete path of js file. I think you are not place that file on proper location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are not looking to override a Core JavaScript file from Magento. You are trying to override a JavaScript file from a Module, in specific, Customer Module from Vendor. The methodology is the same as any other frontend inheritance from the Magento 2 Development process.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html

For JS files within KO file structure, is the same way. If you keep the path but within your same frontend/theme, you are going to be fine. Re-deploy and your file should be there.

PS. The conditional you are trying to put there seems kind of a weird, not the best, fix. But if you are looking for a hotfix, that's ok.

Comment: You mean I should copy the files I need to override to the same path inside my theme dir?

Comment: I copied the (vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/model/customer-addresses.js) to (app/design/frontend/MY-THEME-DIR/Magento_Customer/js/model/customer-addresses.js) is that what you mean ? @Ezequiel

Comment: Well should be 'Magento_Customer/web/js/model/customer-addresses.js' but yes, run grunt to deploy your static files (symlinks) and you will see yours on the frontend of the site. If you want to be sure, run a console.log() to check that it's running properly. @AhmadElkenany

Comment: Thanks bro. It's working now

Comment: No problem! Glad I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below method to override core js file.

**Step 1:**
Create a RequireJS configuration file requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "<default_component>": "<custom_component>"
    }
  }
};
```

Where the following notation is used:

: the name of the default component you replace

: the name of the custom component

Example, if you want to use custom `navigation-menu.js` script instead of the default menu widgets, your `requirejs-config.js` should contain the following:

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "menu": "/js/navigation-menu",
      "mage/backend/menu": "js/navigation-menu",
    }
  }
};
```

**Step 2:**

Place your `requirejs-config.js` file in one of the following directories (it depends on the location of your custom script):

Your theme files: 
Your module view files: `<module_dir>/view/frontend</code>`
The 2 steps I mention above is the shortest process for you to Override Magento JS Core in Magento 2. With this guide, you can manage the Magento JS Core in Magento 2 easily.

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-override-magento-js-core-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

To overide that file you need to do this things.

1. create `requirejs-config.js` at following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer-addresses.js':
                'Vendor_Extension/js/model/customer-addresses.js'
        },

    }
};
```

2. Now copy this file

> 'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer-addresses.js':

at following location.

> 'Vendor_Extension/view/frontend/web/js/model/customer-addresses.js'

and now change it according to your requirement.

Comment: Is there any command i need to run  ?

Comment: I tried, but the file inside vendor is loaded

Comment: Yes you need to run upgrade, deploy, caching command.

Comment: Ok, I will try it

Comment: I tried, but not working

Comment: Is the js folder location in the extension root directory. Or inside the view folder like the original module?

Comment: Confirm that that your customer-addresses.js is at following location.
app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\web\js\modelcustomer-addresses.js.

Comment: This is not the way to override a simple JavaScript file from a Module in Magento 2. This file is not a CORE file. Please read carefully the question and paths, is simple customization of the vendor files like any other process for theme development.